# 'struct <anonymous>' has no member named

Tags: c, struct, queue, member, abstract-data-type

Looking for the way to reference the node and set it to null for the creation function. Any suggestions from that given output to put the front and back nodes in the queue to NULL?

```
gcc -std=c99 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra  -c queueADT.c
queueADT.c:13:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
 };
 ^
queueADT.c: In function 'que_create':
queueADT.c:36:6: error: 'struct <anonymous>' has no member named 'front'
   new->front = NULL;
      ^
queueADT.c:37:6: error: 'struct <anonymous>' has no member named 'rear'
   new->rear = NULL;
      ^
queueADT.c:38:8: error: expected identifier before '*' token
   new->*cmprFunc = NULL;
```

Here is the main part of the code which caused the errors. (2 structs )

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    //size_t num;
    struct node *next;
};


struct QueueADT {
    struct node front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
};


#include "queueADT.h"


/// create a queue that is either sorted by cmp or FIFO
//function with two void
QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {

    QueueADT new;
    new = (QueueADT)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueADT));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
        new->*cmprFunc = NULL;

    } else {
        new->*cmprFunc = &cmp;
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
    }

    return ( new );
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct node {...};` <-- where's the alias? Why is the `typedef` even there? You're also casting the return of `malloc` is a weird way: `(QueueADT)malloc();` <-- `malloc` returns a pointer, but there's no `typedef` of this `QueueADT` to be seen. Lastly: `new` is not a great var name: you will not be able to compile this code if it's part of a C++ project

Comment: I believe you meant `int *cmprFunc(struct node*, struct node *)`

Comment: My .h file has QueueADT written like 'typedef struct { } *QueueADT;'

Comment: no the const void* is abstract data type

Comment: @arrowinfedex: The header file `typedef`'s an anonymous struct as `*QueueADT`, but the C file defines a `struct QueueADT` with members `front` and `rear`, both are different structs entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks invalid to me:

```
    struct QueueADT new;
    new = (QueueADT)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueADT));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        ...
```

Maybe you need this:

```
    struct QueueADT *new;
    new = (struct QueueADT*)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueADT));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        ...
```

**And**:

```
struct QueueADT {
    struct node front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
};
```

should probably be

```
struct QueueADT {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
};
```

**And** the `typedef` here is pointless, it should be removed:

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    //size_t num;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Other issue: these two declarations in `struct QueueADT` look suspicious to me:

```
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
```

Comment: `new->front` can't be set to `NULL` because the member is declared as `struct node front;` (not a pointer)

Comment: My .h file has QueueADT written like `typedef struct { } *QueueADT` which gives the **error** 
`queueADT.h:23:21: error: conflicting types for 'QueueADT'
 typedef struct { } *QueueADT;
                     ^
queueADT.c:21:3: note: previous declaration of 'QueueADT' was here
 }*QueueADT;
   ^`

Comment: @arrowinfedex Update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `typedef` from `typedef struct node {..`
2. Change `struct QueueADT {//body};` to `typedef struct
   {//body}QueueADT;`
3. `QueueADT new;` shoule be `QueueADT *new;`

   and so on..